# How to deploy Azure Function App on Linux from Visual Studio

Tags: linux, azure-functions, publish

How can i deploy an Azure Function App V2 to an existing Linux Function App Plan in Azure from Visual Studio 2019?

When i select "Select existing" from the publish-dialog in Visual Studio i only see my windows-based functions in my connected Azure Subscription, but the Linux one i created in the same subscription is missing.

When i download the publishing profile for the function app, import this and try to publish this way, i get an error which is not very helpful imho:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Publishing failed.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Model.DefaultPublishSteps.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<IsBuildCompletedSuccessfully>b__2()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Model.DefaultPublishSteps.<DefaultCorePublishStep>d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.<RunPublishTaskAsync>d__202.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Publishing failed.<---

System.Exception: Publishing failed.
```

What is the way to publish a C# Azure Function to a Azure Functions running on Linux?

Comment: I also cann't see linux app on Visual Studio when publish. Do you have to use Visual Studio to deploy?

Comment: You can use cmd

Comment: Have my solution solved your problem?

Comment: @BowmanZhu Thank you for your suggestion! I will try asap and report back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.right click your project in Visual Studio. Select 'Open Floder in File Explorer'.**

[image]

**2.Press the win and R keys at the same time, then type "cmd" and click OK.**

[image]

**3.Go to the folder where the project is located.**

[image]

**4.Then use `func azure functionapp publish <APP_NAME>`.**(each `<APP_NAME>` is unique on Azure. in myside, it's name is linuxFunctionAppBowman, you can use the name that you created before.)

[image]

**5.Function been deployed.**

[image]

Comment: You need to install additional tools before you can do this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#publish

Basically install Azure CLI